# Destroy objects per instance

Tags: c#, constructor, garbage-collection, destroy

There are several much more complicated answers out there to a simple question I have, so I'll ask the question in regards to my situation because i can't *quite* figure out what to do based off of those other answers. Garbage collection seems like a danger zone, so I'll err on the side of caution.

I have a `Measurement` object that contains a `Volume` object and a `Weight` object. Depending on which constructor is used, I would like to destroy the opposite object, that is to say, if a user adds a volumetric measurement, I would like to eradicate the weight element of that instance, as it is just bloat at that point. What should be done?

**Edited for clarification:**

```
public class RawIngredient
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Measurement measurement;

    public RawIngredient(string n, double d, Measurement.VolumeUnits unit)
    {
        name = n;
        measurement.volume.amount = (decimal)d;
        measurement.volume.unit = unit;

        //I want to get rid of the weight object on this instance of measurement
    }

    public RawIngredient(string n, double d, Measurement.WeightUnits unit)
    {
        name = n;
        measurement.weight.amount = (decimal)d;
        measurement.weight.unit = unit;

        //I want to get rid of the volume object on this instance of measurement
    }
}
```

**Edited again to show `Measurement`**

```
public class Measurement
{

    public enum VolumeUnits { tsp, Tbsp, oz, cup, qt, gal }
    public enum WeightUnits { oz, lb }

    public Volume volume;
    public Weight weight;
}
```

`Volume` and `Weight` are simple classes with two fields.

Comment: Let the GC do its work and  do nothing :)

Comment: "_Garbage collection seems like a danger zone.._" - Why?

Comment: Unless I am not understanding your question (actual code example would help), why don't you just only instantiate which object you want (`Volume` OR `Weight`) inside the constructor, then there is nothing to "destroy" because you have only created an instance of the one you need.

Comment: The best you can and should do is to free up any references that are no longer required.  Then let the garbage collector do its job.  I.E. If the user sets the Volume property, set the Weight property to null and vice versa.  If you try to manage the memory further you will ultimately cause a minefield of disposed objects.

Comment: So where I have my comments right now I should be writing:

`measurement.weight = null` or 'measurement.volume = null`, is that what I'm understanding? I only asked the question because it seems like I <i>should</i> be getting rid of the opposite instance.

Comment: We need to see the Measurement, volume, and weight definitions. Are they structs? But yes, if they're classes, just set them to null, or better, don't initialize them in the first place (as the answers below suggest).

Comment: Edited to show `Measurement`

Comment: I think you face your problem because what you have written is not very OOP. You want to Measure but allowing different Measurements. Achiving this with one class `Measurement` that contains all different Measurements classes and just the "right" one is set isn't a good design. Instead you should create lets say a IMeasure interface und your `Volume` and `Weight` implement those interfaces. With this you always have just the IMeasurement active that you need/want. And you don't need to check values if there are `null` or set them to `null`

Comment: While I completely agree with what you are saying, whenever I attempt to work around this problem, I return to the same issue: Every food item can be measured either way, and therefore, I have to, at some point, have a null instance that isn't being used. Therefore the argument would just ascend a layer into my `RawIngredient` class with an instance of both `Volume` and `Weight` . I can see no way around this...

Comment: Why not describe your problem into its own question? A question like "how do i design..." and describe your problem what you encounter where you think there is no other way.

Comment: But what i meant. You just have `IMeasure measure { get; set; }` for example in a class. Now you have `Volume` and `Weight` that implements those interfaces. Now you can do `object.measure = new Volume()` or `object.measure = new Weight()`. You just have one attribute to measure, and it can be Volume OR Weight. You don't need two different attributes to save the one or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in the `Measurement` constructor, then simply don't create the non-required type; it will remain as the default value of null (as long as `Volume` and `Weight` are reference types and not structs), and any attempted reference to the wrong type would throw an exception.

As long as the `Measurement` object is in scope, the garbage collector couldn't collect the non-required type, as it would be in the scope of the `Measurement` instance, and could theoretically be created at any time, regardless of your actual intentions in reality.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, what needs to be destroyed?   This is happening in the ctor, so just don't create the one you don't want.

```
class Measurement 
{
    public Volume Volume {get; set;}
    public Weight Weight {get; set;}

   public Measurement (Volume v) { Volumme = v; Weight = null;}
   public Measurement (Weight w) { Volumme = null; Weight = w;}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the objects implement IDisposable, you should call their Dispose method and ensure that they're not referenced or disposed-of again.

After `Dispose`-ing (if necessary), you can set the unused object to `null`.

1. Reference: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2010/02/q-should-i-set-variables-to-null-to.html

Comment: IDisposable is there to free unmanaged ressources. Implementing IDisposable and calling Dispose() on it doesn't mean memory will be freed, the object still exists in memory. If an object don't use an unmanaged ressources then just clearing all references to the object is enough.

Comment: @sid "**If the objects implement IDisposable**, you should call their Dispose method" - he's not suggesting implementing it for no reason.